# Java library for detecting list items on webpages

Tags: java, pattern-matching, html, listitem

Most of the webpages now-a-days contain lists of things, or chunks of html patterns that repeat a lot.

For example:

1. Facebook status messages on homepages.
2. Digg/Hacker News
3. StackOverflow homepage

Is there a Java library for detecting such lists. It will involve some amount of pattern matching and intelligence. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could use regexes?

Comment: It's not that simple. How will you form the regexes if you don't know what the pattern is? Also, the html codes can have slight dissimilarities among them.

Answer (score 0):

Between XPath expressions and HTML element "id" attributes you should be able to find the root of the lists you are interested in, and then more XPath will let you iterate over them.

If you don't have XPath already, I recommend using HtmlUnit.  Yeah, it's meant for testing, but it works really well as "headless" browser and has excellent support for XPath-ing your way around the DOM of a page.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to investigate the term 'scraper' on google.  Pin-point extraction of data from web-pages is loosely called scraping as opposed to capturing the whole page 'crawling'.

Comment: where did i use either of the terms ?